# Avoid Scroll bars when showing content from other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello im new to web developing and i need help on something ! I used jQuery and a javascript code to show content from other page , but sometimes it results showing a scroll bar for example : i made an album and if i add to many photos it shows a scroll bar ..

here is the code and a photo:

```
$("#albumin")
        .html('<object data="http://localhost/album_1.php" width="1320px" height="1500px"/>');
```

[image: link for a screenshoot !]

Comment: Try <object data="http://localhost/album_1.php" style="overflow: hidden;" .../> or add to CSS

Comment: if i remove width = "" and height ="" the page becomes smaller and if i add style ="overflow:hidden; it do nothing ... anyway thanks !

Comment: display:block  and overflow:visible should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
"#albumin")
        .html('<object data="http://localhost/album_1.php" width="1320px" height="1500px" overflow="hidden" />');
```

Or add `#albumin {overflow:hidden;}` into your CSS, should work fine.